# Printing an associative array inside a columned table

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<div class="form-group">
        <td><label for="genre">Names</label></td>
        <td>
        <?php  
        foreach($array as $row){
            echo "<div class='form-check form-check-inline'>";
            echo "<label class='form-check-label'>";
            echo "<input class='form-check-input' type='checkbox' name='genre_checked[]' value='".$row->name."'>";
            echo $row->name;
            echo "<label>";
            echo "</div>";
        }?>
        </td>
    </div>
```

I'm making a form to submit to my controller and inside that form, i am printing an array inside a "" but the way i've coded it is that it will print in a single column from top to bottom and makes the "td" height increase. I wanted to make use of the extra space so instead of increasing the height i atleast wanted to make use of the td width.

Comment: please define a question.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. After a few hours of sleep. Took only 5mins.

```
<?php  
foreach($genre as $row){
    echo "<div class='col-lg-2'>";
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='genre_checked[]' value='".$row->genre_name."'>";
    echo $row->genre_name;
    echo "</div>";
}?>
```